# One page website with Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

I saw many personal or company websites with one-page website style. the one-page design is very good for giving as quick as possible all information that you have without letting users click around to find out who are you and I really want to apply them in Drupal.
I also tried to implement one-page website by using the single page website module (http://drupal.org/project/single_page_website) and it's quite nice for the simple pages.
So my questions are:

1. Which is the best way for making one-page design: create one-page templates or using contributed modules?
2. The advantages and disadvantages for Drupal to make one-page design?

I haven't done any one-page design before so can someone give me the right direction for that.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you want ideas for one page websites you can look here for some awesome one page websites.
    [onepagelove.com](http://onepagelove.com)

you can pick any one of these as design however you will have to heavily custom theme your drupal site.

Comment: Thanks @Prerit Mohan. I know that these templates are good but I really want to know how to build these templates correctly by bare-hand and after that I'll use existed templates

Comment: Your welcome @StoneVo

Comment: For that i would suggest you to go over theming tutorials. Google some tutorials. However why would you want to use a CMS for single page website? I think Html 5 with Css 3 and Jquery+ Javascript is all you need for a superb site . :)

Comment: For sure, we shouldn't use the powerful tool to make just small thing (with just basic functions). That's reason I want to understand what are The advantages and disadvantages by using Drupal to do this stuff. The first advantage that i thought, that allows user can create many sub-sites (one-page style) (similar with flavours.me when they use to create the responsive sub-sites)

Comment: Hey this will solve all your queries , good resource
http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/the-science-behind-a-single-page-website/
@StoneVo

Answer (score 3):

Here is another possible solution; [Pageflow](https://drupal.org/project/pageflow). This module is theme agnostic & provides single page navigation support which is very handy. Here's a general list of features;

- Single page navigation support
- Sticky header & footer toggle
- Horizontal & vertical scrolling support
- Unlimited Pageflows
- Theme agnostic
- Administration UI
- CSS & JS aggregation works as expected
- Boost & core caching support

This module has been tested with a number of popular caching mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use drupal for a one page site. But Drupal was not made for that - it`s a very powerful and weightful. 
There are plenty of other lightweight cms you might use for this purposes.

The advantages could be if you had not worked with any other cms or/and want to use drupal flexebility and possibilities.

The disadvantages were mentioned: you could hardly achieve a fast page load, even if this would be the only page on your site and without any unneeded modules enabled.

I would prefer any of javscript mvc frameworks to make a one page application. It would work lightning fast.

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote for the module [Single Page Site](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site) since it is not theme dependent. (Not to confuse with another module [Single Page Website](https://www.drupal.org/project/Single_Page_Website).)

**Single page Site:**

> This module provides functionality to create a single page website.
>   It allows you to automatically create a single page from a menu. The module will render all the content from the links, that are configured in the menu, on one page. It will then override the menu links so that they refer to an anchor instead of a new page.

Comment: Yep ! That module is quite good. Only problem is the navigation not scroll smooth